# Column Calculator

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following table and want to know how to set up a column `total` to calculate the sum of the row. I want the `total` column to calculate `first_bid - second_bid`.

```
id |      First Bid |    Second Bid   |        Total
0  |        7       |         1       |  (first_bid)-(second_bid)
1  |        8       |         2       |  
2  |        5       |         3       |  
3  |        4       |         4       |  
4  |        5       |         5       |  
5  |        5       |         6       |
```

I need to display to the user all previous bids and total on a page. The total should be in descending order also.

Comment: do you want to populate it one off? run it when the bids change? run it when the data is displayed? super basic example `SELECT ... (first_bid-second_bid) as total ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just calculate the total when you are querying the database.

```
SELECT first_bid, second_bid, (first_bid - second_bid) as total FROM table ORDER BY 3 DESC
```

Something along these lines

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT id, First_Bid, Second_Bid, First_Bid - Second_Bid AS Total
```

For the grand total, you'd have to run a second query with `SUM()` aggregate functions. Which is somewhat redundant, since you can just do the summation in your client as you retrieve the data. e.g.

```
$total = 0;
while($row = fetch_from_db($result)) {
    $total += $result['Total'];
    ... display row data ...
}
... display total ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
SELECT *, (First Bid-Second Bid) as total from TABLE
```